# Bind conditional parameters from different types to a query

Tags: java, spring, ejb, jdbctemplate

I have a simple query which can take various conditional parameters if they are specified n the method:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE userId = ?";

ArrayList<Object> dataBindings = new ArrayList<Object>();
dataBindings.add(userId);

if(startDate != null && !startDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
    SQL += " AND datev BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    dataBindings.add(startDate);
    dataBindings.add(endDate);
}

if (argn > 0) {
    SQL += " AND argn = ?";
    dataBindings.add(argn);
}


List<SomeObject> someObjectList = this.jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new RowMapper<SomeObject>() {
        // using anonymous inner class RowMapper here
        public SomeObject mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
            o.setId(rs.getInt("idobj"));                
            ...
            return s;
        }
}, dataBindings.toArray());
```

But I get the error: `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

I have to specify the type of each argument, but as I pass an array of Objects to `query()`, it can't determinate which argument is a String or integer.

How could I achieve this?

EDIT : I tried this way but I think it could be more elegant because I check at least two times each condition because i can't know the index of the parameter I am going to pass without checking again these conditions

```
try {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = (ComboPooledDataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
    PreparedStatement ps = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
    ps.setLong(1, userId);

    if(startDate != null && !startDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        ps.setString(2, startDate);
        ps.setString(3, endDate);
    }

    if (argn > 0) {
        if(startDate != null && !startDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            ps.setInt(3, argn);
        } else {
            ps.setInt(2, argn);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I can't use RowMapper here

So I could do :

```
final String finalSqlQuery = SQL;
jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
                            throws SQLException {
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(finalSqlQuery);
             if(startDate != null && !startDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                   ps.setString(2, startDate);
                   ps.setString(3, endDate);
             }

             if (argn > 0) {
                  if(startDate != null && !startDate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                      ps.setInt(3, argn);
                  } else {
                      ps.setInt(2, argn);
                  }
             }

        }
    }, new RowMapper<SomeObject>() {

            public SomeObject mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
                o.setId(rs.getInt("idobj"));                
                ...
                return s;
           }
    });
```

but it seems really ugly to me to determinate parameters' indexes by checking again the conditions

Comment: The `JdbcTemplate` will match the sql parameter position with each index of the passed array. I would assume it's using `PreparedStatement#setObject()`. Can you try using a PreparedStatement yourself instead of the `jdbcTemplate`?

Comment: I don't know how to append a statement to an existing `PreparedStatement`depending on the conditions to add

Comment: Build the SQL string statement first, then pass it to create the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: so I will have to make a `final`copy of the previsouly 
built sql string which I can use in `createPreparedStatement()`

Comment: Why does it need to be `final`? Call `prepareStatement(String)` on `java.sql.Connection` instance, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)

Comment: it needs to be final to call `jdbctemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator{...}, new RowMapper<T>);` if I use jdbctemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(), I can't use my RowMapper when querying on `jdbctemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()`

Comment: Just grab a `Connection` object from your `DataSource`, don't use `jdbcTemplate` for now.

Comment: I am working in a DAO class and I only have a Jdbctemplate member in this class, no DataSource object (maybe due to the underlying connection pooling) so I can't get the DataSource object without using jdbctemplate

Comment: It's Spring, just inject it from your config. `@Autowired Datasource datasource;` This is just for debugging.

Comment: c3p0 is managing the connections so except a velocityEngine and a mailSender there is nothing in spring beans.xml so I can't use @Autowired, but I can use this : `InitialContext context = new InitialContext();`
  `ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = (ComboPooledDataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/myDB");`